# Why is Windows 7 professional x64 Available Physical Memory gradually declining with time?

Tags: windows-7, memory

If I refresh windows System Information, over and over, it reports my Available Physical Memory is gradually declining.

In the past hour it has declined about 1gb.  Interestingly, once I've even seen Available Physical Memory go up a little, but mostly it has been a slow gradual decline.  It does seem to gradually slow the rate of decline.  But so far I haven't actually seen it stop the decline.

[image]

I have already carefully looked at the System Information | Hardware Resources | Memory report of where it's being allocated.  I sucked that table into a data base so I could accurately compare from refresh to refresh, to possibly find which component was using more memory, but those numbers are not changing from refresh to refresh.

I think it might be some sort of system or driver memory leak.  Dare I ask if anyone has any ideas as to what's going on?  Is it that Available Physical Memory isn't what we really think it is?  Or is it that some sort of system buffer is taking some before  Available is calculated?  Or might it be a leak?  And if so, how to debug it?

[I know a bunch of other questions have asked about low Windows 7 Available Physical Memory, but so far I haven't seen any discussion about this actually changing, especially on a Windows Professional x64 system, which is suppose to support something like 128gb of physical.]

hp Pentium dv7t CoreDuo box.

Comment: We have no idea what processes you have running so we cannot tell you what is using your available memory.

Comment: There should always be "Available Memory" in Windows 7's Task Manager.  It is the "Free Memory" that is allowed to go to 0.

If Task Manager's "Memory (Private Bytes)" column for all processes does not add up approximately Total-Available memory then there is something more involved going on.  Try using the Microsoft Sysinternals [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) tool to help you see what is actually using your RAM.  In RAMMap anything marked as "active memory" is physically in RAM.

Comment: Reboot....and.. Fixed!

Comment: I'm a Linux person, so its (educated) speculation.  I wonder if the issue is not a memory leak as much as Windows using "otherwise empty" memory as cache - certainly Linux does this, and I'd be surprised if Windows doesn't.   Effectively the opposite of SWAP !!!

Comment: RAMMap was quite useful.  Thank you.  The color codes on the left and right are helpful I think.  I'm still not quite sure what to think of it all, but this is a great simple tool to keep an eye on things with.

Comment: @davidgo I think you are probably right.  But I was having this resource gadget telling me I never used more than about 1/3 of my memory which didn't seem correct.  I fixed some things (new bios and chip-set driver) and wanted to see if in fact my memory was getting used or it was just sitting there unused.  Quite a few other people have also had suspicions that their memory was not getting fully used so this partly led to mine too.

Comment: @Ramhound Good question.  I had a fresh boot with only System information, Notepad++, and MS Access running.  Not much really.  Not enough to suck up an extra free gig I don't think.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 _"If Task Manager's "Memory (Private Bytes)" column for all processes does not add up approximately Total-Available memory then there is something more involved going on. "_ Sorry but no. The Private Bytes counter is process-private virtual address space. "Available" memory is physical memory, not virtual, and it is RAM that is not currently assigned to any process. The two have nothing to do with each other and there is no desired equality relationship between the two.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan While I don't remember exactly the names Windows 7 gave the metrics, and I think I made a typo. I believe I meant the sum of `private working sets` of all processes + available memory should ROUGHLY equal total physical ram. I know this is not exact, particularly when the system is running low on memory, or busy flushing the disk cache, which is why I was talking about something more involved going on if they are significantly different, due to additional factors, such as system memory not associated with any process, and MANY more factors, that don't fit in to a comment.

Comment: Well... what you're talking about now would not be a sign of a problem, or a goal to achieve, but rather a way of adding things up to account for where all the RAM is. But you're not accounting at all for shared working sets. Nor indeed for nonpaged pool, the resident portion of paged pool and of page tables, the nonpageable OS and driver code, etc. RAMmap's "active" column breaks this down best.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that what they really mean by 'Available Physical Memory' is really "*Remaining* Available Physical Memory" (or a more variable thing), not "Available Physical Memory" (which I had thought of as a more static thing).

My next question is: remaining after what?  This is not so clear, but it appears that RAMMap will help clarify this in time.

Thank you to all of you for looking at this.

Answer (score -1):

"Available Memory" gradually going down is absolutely normal. Over time programs simply will use more and more memory. It happens with EVERY program. It's called a "memory leak".

Comment: It will not happen with every program. It should happen with **none**. Memory leaks are bugs. It means the programmer made a mistake. It means the program is broken. It should be fixed. It should not happen in normal cases.