# windowx 7 x64 only uses 2GB of ram

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I have just installed windows 7 SP1 on my new 64 bit AMD APU. the motherboard has 4GB of ram, andf the "Clickbios" application in windows confirms the presence of 4GB of ram. however, windows only uses 2GB of it. I saw a suggestion to check the resource monitor to see how much was reserved, and that was about 500-550MB. all the remaining portions added to that number added up to 2GB of ram, which is odd. 
it's activated, so it isn't the license function. MSCONFIG does NOT have the max memory option checked. what is causing windows to not use all of the hardware memory?

to clarify, windows isn't saying "4GB installed, 2GB useable", it's saying "2GB installed"

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of Task Manager's *Performance* tab?

Comment: here's a screenshot of the tab: http://postimg.org/image/h7xd1xdzt/

Comment: Is it one stick of memory?

Comment: it is 2 sticks of RAM, 2GB each
(I can tell it's 2GB each because Clickbios correctly lists 4GB of RAM. windows, on the other hand, thinks there's only 2GB total)

Comment: Its a long shot but are they the same speed wise,or sometimes faulty sticks might be seen in bios but cause trouble in windows.Or try replacing their slots.

Comment: the slots(sockets) are fused to the motherboard (DDR3 system memory). 
the RAM I inserted into the slots came in a 4GB kit.

Comment: I meant changing their slots if you have more than 2 or interchanging to check for faulty slot.

Comment: the motherboard has 4 slots total, 2 filled. 1 and 3 are filled, which puts them in duel channel mode. I think that they are working due to the fact that the bios recognizes the RAM(I've had cases on other motherboards where they would get ignored if there was a problem)

Comment: ok, I noticed that according to CPU-Z they aren't duel channel after all. 
http://postimg.org/image/81f2en8rd/
the sticks themselves are identical on the SPD tab with the exception of the serial number, which is different for them.

Comment: You could try running something like [Memtest68](http://www.memtest.org/) to make sure all 4 GB is installed and working properly.

Comment: memtest86 gives a weird result. is says no errors but it guesses the APU and the ram wrong. (might be an older version though,I could try burning the latest to disk)

Comment: I read that the GPU doesn't have any dedicated memory and depends on the system memory. since it's tightly integrated with the CPU it's possible that it's allocating those bytes to it's self before windows boots

Answer (score 0):

From your start menu search box type in and run "System Information" and tell us what that says please.  There are a bunch of other threads on this here with quite a bit more information so take a look at those too.  I just got done with this issue but rather than say it all over, be best if you can say what has been said already.  It's not so simple.

(I would post this as a comment but am just new to this site and don't have the points to do that yet.)

Comment: like this http://postimg.org/image/odp44dn2x/

Comment: I think you are ok but not sure.  You might want to run memory test in bios (i.e. hit escape just after you power on).  Also download RAMMap from internet and run that to see what you can see.

Comment: it's odd because clickbiosII and CPU-Z show the right amount. it's like Windows it's self is ignoring it. I have Home premium- do I need professional to use it all?

Comment: I think there is confusion in terms used to describe memory. Available Physical Memory as reported by ms actually looks to be better described as Remaining Available Physical Memory. I've seen the number change, both go up and down as time goes on. There is more behind this than is evident from the surface.  Anyway, so long as your bios memory test is ok, and so long as you have an updated bios and chipset driver and are not seeing any other errors I think you are ok.  Also as you use superuser.com be sure to give people answering your questions some points by clicking the up arrows. Thanks

Comment: See this post for details about my last point above: http://superuser.com/questions/692831/why-is-windows-7-professional-x64-available-physical-memory-gradually-declining?noredirect=1#comment880680_692831

Comment: RamMap says 1,552,680k total. this is a little different then the posts that say "it says installed but it's only using xyz", in this case the installed number is low.